# Как определить спящий режим?

Tags: windows, winforms, visual-basic, .net

У меня есть программа, которая каждый час выполняет какое-то действие (VS-2010 > Visual Basic). 1 час отсчитывается с помощью таймера (`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`) в 1 секунду...
 Так вот, если программа работает и компьютер переходит в спящий режим, то при возобновлении его работы сразу выполняется это действие (которое должно выполнится только через 1 час).

Подскажите мне, пожалуйста, как мне определить, ушёл ли компьютер в спящий режим?

Честно говоря, я вообще не понимаю, почему так происходит. Ведь компьютер вообще с виду совсем выключен. BIOS-часы?

P.S. Это сообщество не перестаёт меня радовать..

Comment: 1. Спящий режим как долго продолжается - больше часа?
2. Как понимать фразу "1 час отсчитывается с помощью таймера в 1 секунду"? Таймер срабатывает каждую секунду и как только насчитаете час, так и выполняете действие?

Comment: 1. Само собой, спящий режим продолжается больше часа.
2. Это значит, что есть некоторый таймер, у которого Interval = 1000 и переменная, которая наращивается при Timer1_Tick и тем же проверяется, не равна ли она 3600, иначе <действие>.  

«Таймер срабатывает каждую секунду и как только насчитаете час, так и выполняете действие?» - именно так.

Comment: Почему не создали таймер, который будет срабатывать раз в час, а не каждую секунду?

Comment: Потому что мне НУЖНО, чтобы была возможность приостановить отсчёт времени..

Comment: Разница есть и очень большая - во время спящего режима ваш счетчик не увеличивается, а система секунды продолжает считать...

Comment: @BStudio Уважаемый участник, старайтесь избегать личных замечаний и оценок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переход в спящий режим отслеживается в .NET по событию:

```
Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged
```

В Windows API по событию:

```
WM_POWERBROADCAST
```

А в WMI по событию:

```
Win32_PowerManagementEvent
```

Comment: первая строка работает и очень радует... ну почему я не могу плюсанууууть....!

Answer (score 4):

Лучше по таймеру не увеличивать счётчик, а проверять время последнего срабатывания нужного события. Если время срабатывания отличается от текущего на час или больше, обновляем время срабатывания текущим временем и запускаем операцию.

Comment: ВАУ!!.. Ответ гениален.. Я думал подобными способами, но так нет.. =)
Спасибо.

Comment: Просто каждую секунду проверять, Date.Compare(lastcheck, Now) =D

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте срабатывание таймера раз в час и будет все хорошо, после выхода из спящего режима. Не нужно создавать переменную для счетчика секунд - это неуместно: за вас система может считать.

Comment: Понимаете, просто мне крайне необходимо, чтобы была возможность паузы. А стандартный таймер таких возможностей не предусматривает...

Comment: Таймер всегда можно остановить (приостановить, насколько помню, действительно нельзя), а потом запустить заново с того же места - почему не так делаете?

Comment: Можно написать свой таймер, который будет приостанавливаться по необходимости. Это проще, чем отслеживать спящий режим.

Comment: Не знаю насчёт языков программирования, о которых вы говорите, но в Visual Basic.NET таймеры такого не предусматривают..

Comment: @BStudio Вы программируете под .NET и таймер System.Windows.Forms имеет метод Stop(). От языка это не зависит.

Comment: @IAZ Stop() - это значит полный стоп.. =) и не от языка, а, наверное, от платформы.. и кстати, в цивилизованном pascal'е по-моему вообще delay(msec) есть (задержка)..

Comment: @BStudio после стопа можно Start() вызвать. А delay не из той оперы.

Comment: @BStudio Что такое "сброс таймера в нуль"? Таймер просто срабатывает через опредленные промежутки времени (генерируется сообщение WM_TIMER каждые указанные секунды/минуты), после Stop перестает это делать, после Start опять начинает.

Comment: @IAZ т.е. если интервал таймера = 3600000 и прошло, допустим 1800000 с момента Start() то при Stop() и обратно Start() событие выполниться через 3600000, а не через 3600000 - 1800000. Вы не понимаете, что такое пауза ?

Comment: @BStudio перечитайте нашу переписку, я уже говорил что приостановки нет, а Start запускает заново таймер. И не хами, тебе помогают решить твою проблему и ты за это не платишь, по этому хотя бы уважай чужую точку зрения.

Answer (score 0):

Гибернация прекращает выполнение любого кода, процессор остановлен. Само собой понятно что после пробуждения все события будут развёрнуты.

> Ведь компьютер вообще с виду совсем
> выключен. BIOS-часы?

Этими часами(RTC) как и таймерами апик(профайлер), PIT etc. занимается ядро. Данный функционал только халу доступен, никак не для VB :)

Кмоса часики могут включить питание, если их корректно закодить ;)

Comment: Да, есть такая тема 'часы пробуждения'.. В 7-ой виндовс включала мне комп в 4 ночи =D... или ещё того хуже, когда я не дома.

Comment: Во первых версия оси не имеет значения, так как этим занимаются драйвера соответствующие(алго подсчёта чексумм кмоса уникален для плат разных производителей).
Во вторых вы с настройками разберитесь http://hpfan.ru/forum/index.php?topic=203.0

Comment: Во-первых, мне не важно имеет версия оси значение или нет, просто на виндовс семь я такое видывал своими глазами и могу сказать с уверенностью. Во-вторых, у меня нет такой проблемы. В настройках электропитания (контрол пэнэл =D имеет) там даже начинающий юзернейм разобрался бы, как выключить таймеры пробуждения.

Comment: Что значит 'алго подсчёта' & 'чексумма CMOS'a'? sha-1?

Comment: Это значит что смещение начала блока, конца блока и число блоков для которых вычисляется чексумма вам не известна также как и оси, посему это не может быть реализовано без драйверов чипсета.